# C# smtpclient.send is very slow on development but fast on production

Tags: c#, iis, exchange-server, smtpclient

We have some C# code that sends an email to the user when an order is place or when a password is changed, etc. This code runs quickly on the production server but very slow when it is run on our local desktops when doing development. The production server will send an email in under 5 seconds however the development machines take 5 minutes. The development machines and the production server use the same smtp server which is local to our network. Are there any settings in IIS or Exchange that might cause a delay like this in one environment but not in another similar environment? The desktops are running windows 7, the webserver is running windows webserver 2008 and the Exchange server is 2010 running on Microsoft SBS 2011.

Comment: They use the same server, but are they on the same subnet? I suspect there's a proxy between the dev machines and the SMTP server, and negotiating that is taking the time.

Comment: A wireshark packet sniff could shed some light on things.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have Symantec (or other Antivirus / Email protection) software installed on your dev machine? We had similar issues with out going SMTP traffic being stalled or killed when sending email.  The production servers usually have exceptions built in for this traffic already thus no delay.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue while sending email through some smtp client. Whereas this might not be the exact solution you're looking at, you can think of seggregating the sendmail method as a `Non-Blocking task' (using TPL) and let the underlying thread take care of this execution. 
Meanwhile rest of your code can perform as usual.
In this way,. even if the sendmail is taking couple of secs your other part of the code will not have to wait for it.